# Change color of placeholder for select field in sencha

Tags: css, sencha-touch

I am able to achieve for input field using css

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red !important;
}
```

But what about select field? Fyi, I am using sencha framework.
Really appreciate if someone could help me out.

Comment: you mean if you click the input text field?

Comment: For input field i am able to change the color of the placeholder. But not for selectfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that might help. You could be fighting the styles already applied to the component.

### Option 1

The more specific you are in the css the higher priority something has.

For example:

```
input[type=text]::-webkit-input-placeholder,
input[type=password]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: red;
}
```

Another thing is the select field is actually using a textfield.

[image: Sencha touch select field]

### Option 2

You could set a default first select option and the normal text color will get applied.

```
xtype: 'selectfield',
label: 'Marital Status',
labelWidth: '60%',
options: [{
    text: 'Select',
    value: 'select'
}, {
    text: 'Married',
    value: 'Married'
}]
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a psuedo selector.

```
select option:checked{
    color: red;
}
```